# error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Card'

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initialization, card

So, the title is the error code that I get, and I am not experienced enough to see where the problem lies. I have quite a bit of code here that I would love to get some help with too, see where the problem lies.

main.cpp - the rest of the main code is as usual, so nothing wrong underneath the photo

[image]

card.cpp

[image]

card.h - part one

[image]

card.h - part two

[image]

cardDeck.h

[image]

cardDeck.cpp

[image]

I don't really know what to do here, but I have tried to see if I have any sort of syntax errors.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not the set of images.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining that it can't construct a `Card` object.  There are only 2 places in your code where a `Card` object is being constructed:

- In `main()`. You are constructing a `Card` object correctly.  So this is not the problem.
- In `CardDeck`'s constructor. You are constructing 52 default `Card` objects in your `cardVector` (this is the problem!), and then replacing them with new `Card`s in a loop.

The replacement `Card`s are being constructed correctly.  However, `cardVector.resize()` requires `Card` to be default-constructible when adding new elements to the vector. But `Card` is not default-constructible, because it has only 1 user-defined constructor which requires a `Suit` and a `Rank` as input (thus the compiler-generated default constructor is disabled), and you are not providing a default constructor of your own.

So, you need to either:

- give `Card` a default constructor, eg:

  ```
  class Card {
      private:
          Suit s;
          Rank r;

      public:
          Card() : s(), r() {} // <-- HERE
          Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) : s(suit), r(rank) {}
          ...
  };
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  class Card {
      private:
          Suit s;
          Rank r;

      public:
          Card() : Card(Suit(), Rank()) {} // <-- HERE
          Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) : s(suit), r(rank) {}
          ...
  };
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  class Card {
      private:
          Suit s{};
          Rank r{};

      public:
          Card() = default; // <-- HERE
          Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) : s(suit), r(rank) {}
          ...
  };
  ```
- use the `std::vector`'s `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` method instead of the `resize()` method when populating the `cardVector` with new `Card`s, eg:

  ```
  CardDeck::CardDeck(){
      //cardVector.resize(52);
      cardVector.reserve(52);
      //int index = 0;

      for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
          for (int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++){
              //cardVector.at(index) = Card(static_cast<Suit>(suit), static_cast<Rank>(rank));
              cardVector.push_back(Card(static_cast<Suit>(suit), static_cast<Rank>(rank)));
              //or:
              cardVector.emplace_back(static_cast<Suit>(suit), static_cast<Rank>(rank));

              //index++;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

That being said, since a deck has a fixed 52 `Card`s, you might consider using a fixed-sized array (or `std::array`) instead of `std::vector`.